# FormData Ajax not posting data in PHP

Tags: php, ajax

Hope you can help me with my problem.

The problem is that i put my `data` in `FormData` but when i'm calling them in php file using `echo` there is no values and data existing and gives me `error`

> an `undefined variable`

But when im using `var_dump()` or `print_r()` it show all the `values`. and also if i `var_dump` the files for the images it throws me also an `error`.

Here in `html`:

```
<form id="form" action="myurl.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="return false">
   <input type="file" name="image" accept="image/*"/>
   <input type="text" name="description"/>
   <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Here is my code in `ajax`:

```
 function getName(key)
 {
    key = document.getElementsByName(key)[0];
    return key;
 }
 function getId(key)
 {
    key = document.getElementById(key);
    return key;
 }

 var url = getId('form').getAttribute('action');
 var datas = new FormData();
 var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

 var image = getName('image').value.trim();
 var description = getName('description').value.trim();

 datas.append('file_image', image.files[0]);
 datas.append('description', description);

 xhr.open('POST', url, true);
 xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
 xhr.send(datas);

 xhr.onreadystatechange = function()
 {
    var OK = 4;
    var DONE = 200;

    if(xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == DONE)
    {
       alert(xhr.responseText);
    }
 }
```

now in my `myurl.php` php file

```
var_dump($_POST);
var_dump($_FILES);
```

We don't actually using third party `script` like `jQuery`. We practice native `javascript` language.

Thank you.

Comment: Check there, https://plainjs.com/javascript/ajax/send-ajax-get-and-post-requests-47/

Comment: HTML file input, 
"datas.append("file_image", fileInputElement.files[0]);"

Comment: @BhupeshKushwaha i also did that already but when im using var_dump the files there is no values, but in post there was a one value which is where the image located temporarily.

Comment: Have your tried encodeURIComponent

Comment: @kim-dev  read this url : http://unitedwebsoft.in/blog/jqueryajax-file-upload-php/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to append the element manually to form data, create FormData from the form itself.

Give your form a name `name="upload-image`

```
<form id="form" action="myurl.php" name="upload-image" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="image" accept="image/*"/>
    <input type="text" name="description"/>
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

In your Javascript

```
var form = document.forms.namedItem("upload-image");
var url = form['action'];
form.addEventListener('submit', function(ev) {

    var oData = new FormData(form);

    var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
    oReq.open("POST", url, true);
    oReq.onload = function(oEvent) {
        if (oReq.status == 200) {
            alert(oReq.responseText);
        } else {
            alert(oReq.status + " occurred when trying to upload your file.");
        }
    };

    oReq.send(oData);
    ev.preventDefault();
}, false);
```

Comment: did you give your form a name?

Comment: i already figure it out. i must put in the window.load function load first so that it will load the name after the window completely loaded

Comment: but now the problem is that the data i sent i cant get them in specific means if i echo them out undefined variable but when i var_dump them it will show in array

Comment: similar to this problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47974797/formdata-ajax-to-php?noredirect=1#comment82919450_47974797

Comment: In your PHP, use `$file = $_FILES['image'];
        $fileName = $file['name'];
        $fileTmpName = $file['tmp_name'];`

Comment: I already did that, but the problem is that there was no defined variable when i get them in specific but when i var_dump them it shows all the variables that i sent.